# What are the requirements of the 'Chuck Yeager' hat?

Tags: support, winterbash

I found out that I got this hat and I wonder why?

Comment: It's a secret and you have to be fast to get it.

Comment: @3ventic fast at what?

Comment: That would spoil the secret

Comment: I too, got it by accident. It's a secret to everybody!

Comment: I think I figured it out, but I'd hate to spoil the secret since 3ventic seems so eager to keep it. =)

Comment: @3ventic maybe post the answer, but as a spoiler . . .